# Convert list of struct to a list of another struct when second struct uses a subset of fields

Tags: go, struct

I have two structs, `Foo` and `Bar`. `Bar` uses a subset of of `Foo` fields:

```
type Foo struct {
    Id    string
    Name  string
    Extra string
}

type Bar struct {
    Id   string
    Name string
}
```

I want to convert `Foo`s to `Bar`s. I'm currently doing it like this:

```
bars := []Bar

for _, foo = range foos {
    bars = append(
        bars,
        Bar{Id: foo.Id, Name: foo.name}
    )
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in Go?

Comment: Is it possible that you can move `Bar` inside `Foo` so that `Foo` only contains `Extra` field and field of type `Bar` ?

Comment: For this kind of operations I would recommend https://github.com/imdario/mergo library. Check the examples, probably they will fit your use case

Answer (score 1):

You can [embed](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#embedding) `Bar` into `Foo`.

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Bar
    Extra string
}

type Bar struct {
    Id   string
    Name string
}
```

```golang
var bars []Bar

for _, foo = range foos {
    bars = append(bars, foo.Bar)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately in this case I can't embed Bar into Foo.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you state that `Bar` contains a subset of fields but you cannot have `Foo` contain a `Bar`. This tells me that they are in-fact **not** a subset and are unrelated structs.

As a possible way to keep your intentions clearer in your code, you could do `ToBar` on the `Foo` something like this:

```
type Foo struct {
    Id    string
    Name  string
    Extra string
}

func (foo *Foo) ToBar() Bar {
    return Bar{Id: foo.Id, Name: foo.Name}
}

type Bar struct {
    Id   string
    Name string
}
```